# Show deleted answers

Tags: support

Where can I see all my deleted answers?

I found such a link somewhere in my profile a few days ago, but I can't find it now. I want to undelete one of my answers that I have just accidentally deleted.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted

Comment: Look for the page in your browser's history, when in the direct page containing the answer you will see it and can click "undelete" from there. Otherwise, a moderator will have to lend you a hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. While you can see your own deleted answers if you have a link to the answer/corresponding question, you need to ask a moderator if you want a list of all your deleted answers.